# Waiting for a promise to be resolved in a different controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm struggling to AngularJS trying to get a piece of code delayed until a promised will be resolved.

My promise is being called and executed in Controller A, but i need a piece of code from Controller B to delay its execution until the promise from Controller A will be totally resolved.

I've been doing some kind of hacks with `$scope.$watch` but i'm sure there must be another different way to accomplish this.

Am I wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

> My promise is being called and executed in Controller A, but i need a piece of code from Controller B to delay its execution until the promise from Controller A will be totally resolved.

In this case I would use `$rootScope.$broadcast`.

One controller sends *broadcast* message to other controller (*or to anyone who listens*)

See good example in <kbd>[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/2530/)</kbd>

Comment: NICE! This is why I participate in these. I learned something new. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially also do this with a service.

If you can post some code I can be more specific...but....a service which is injected into both controllers allow you to access common data. So you have controller B not execute until some "done" flag is set in service by controller A.

[Link to service API doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services)